# passing arguments to nosetest

Tags: python, unit-testing, command-line-arguments, nose

I write my nose unit tests to be fairly complete, but as a result they can take a while to run. I would like to be able to pass in an optional command-line argument to run some quick version of the tests (e.g. try a handful of possible inputs, instead of every possible input).

Ideally, I'd be able to say something like:

`nosetest --quick my_module/tests/my_test.py`

And in my_test.py, have:

```
def test_something():
    if nose.command_line_args.quick:
        <run quick test>
    else:
        <run long test>
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I know that one way might be to write a nose plugin, but I got scared away when the docs said I needed to install any plugins I write using setuptools. Learning setuptools to install a nose plugin all to just pass in a flag is a bit of yak-shaving I'd love to avoid if I can.

Comment: maybe you could move the fixtures to separate modules and use an env variable to switch between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good way is to decorate your tests with [attributes](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) and thus split them in groups. Say you could have 'unit' for quick and isolated tests and 'integration' for more long-running and thorough tests. You can then run those groups selectively with `nose -a attrname`

Comment: It seems from your link that this is the way recommended by the nosetest authors. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. This feature is really helpful and exists in every testing framework. It let's you run single test or a package of tests. Nose implementation is by far the best I've seen though. It even allows you to combine you tags/attributes!

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem when i want to run all tests but still pass in some argument. In my case im passing in test domain as an env variable.

Comment: you can wrap nose execution into your own script and handle arguments however you like. To programmatically run nose you can do: nose.run(argv=your_params)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think `nosetests` offers any way for you to add custom command-line options (except that of course you can edit its code to customize it for you, but that may not be practical).

In typical Unixy shells, however, you can set **environment variables** on the fly for any given command:

```
$ NOSEQUICK=1 nosetests my_module/tests/my_test.py
```

then in your code you can check `if os.getenv('NOSEQUICK', ''):`.